# Flutter: Android app stuck on splash some times while installing and some times when we reopen

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to flutter and implemented one small application which android splash screen. It is working fine when I ran it on emulator and physical device connect to system. But when I release a build for testing some times it is stucking on installing and some times installing working fine but when we reopen the app from background after some time. Since it is working fine on in debug, I am unable to find the reason. When I look at the firebase crash log, I have a crash with below log. Could someone educate why it is causing this? Thanks.

```
io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.nativeSurfaceChanged (FlutterJNI.java)
io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.onSurfaceChanged (FlutterJNI.java)
io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.FlutterRenderer.surfaceChanged (FlutterRenderer.java)
io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView.changeSurfaceSize (FlutterSurfaceView.java)
io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView.access$300 (FlutterSurfaceView.java)
io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView$1.surfaceChanged (FlutterSurfaceView.java)
android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface (SurfaceView.java:1273)
android.view.SurfaceView.setFrame (SurfaceView.java:646)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:23477)
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:23482)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6575)
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:23482)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6575)
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:23482)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6575)
android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1841)
android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:23482)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6575)
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:873)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:23482)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6575)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:4075)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2398)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9407)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1214)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:968)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:868)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1199)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8204)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:589)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1071)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue logged with Flutter repo on Github. You can find it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98779).

You should upgrade you flutter version to  Flutter 2.10.3. as it is claimed in same thread that the version 2.10.3 has resolved this issue now.